# I need an opinion on what happened during my exit

Tags: software-industry

I entered a company in the middle of May. Because I am a new hire, it was explicitly mentioned to me that I am under probation.

I was told to leave last week.

This was what happened during the exit:

My boss told me that he has been closely looking at how much progress I have made, he says that it falls short of expectations. He also mentions that I didn't meet the expected understanding of using a 3rd party library in order to create an improved version of an existing software. He also mentions I have told him that I will struggle to understand the source code of a system someone else earlier has written.

He told me that his company's intention is not to provide training for a new hire but for the new hire to really get started working immediately. He told me that I should further train and educate myself even further if I wanted to be a software developer.He told me to keep exploring what other software tools people are using in the market. He told me that I am young and I can keep trying harder.

I asked him if there was any miscommunication in the job interview where we talked about my previous work experience. His reply was that there was no miscommunication. He told me that it is very hard to know what really took place during my previous work during the job interview. So he has to let me come in and see for himself.

My manager told me that if I wanted to be a software developer, I can think about undergoing further training. He also mentioned that I can also focus on 'doing my own thing' if I have some sort of idea.

I understood what all of them said. I also accepted what all of them said.

I posted this question here because I just wanted to see if anyone can give me any objective opinion on what happened. That is all. Thank you.

Comment: Giving out opinions on what we think based on your recap of someone else word sounds very much off-topic here as it will be just anyone's opinion with nothing hard to back it up. What exactly are you hoping to take away from the answers here?

Comment: What is unclear? It looks quite clear to me.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul . Maybe I am just curious if that is all that is and I no need to overthink it?

Comment: @JC6T overthinking what? You were let go citing that your work is not good enough. Simple enough, time to move on.

Comment: Two people mentioned to you that you can "become" a software developer. What is your background? On what grounds were you hired?

Comment: @nvoigt . I have a degree in software engineering. I had some prior work experience writing code.

Comment: You were hired as a software developer; your boss fired you after two weeks and expressed a hope that you could **become** a software developer. You clearly were a long way below that person's expectations. Since you earned a degree and wrote code before, this implies it's the person's expectations that are wrong. Still, you need to be very careful choosing your next job to ensure they aren't a "hit the ground running" place that could turn out similarly.

Comment: Did you get paid for the time you worked there? If not - it's most likely a violation of your country's labor code. Hopefully, this wasn't just a tricky (and abusive) interviewing tactic on their end.

Answer (score 3):

Overall this feels very strange. If you got canned after only two weeks that either means that you messed up big time somewhere (which you should be aware of) or something else is going on which might have nothing to do with you at all (budget, political, priority/strategy shift, etc.). No performance related firing should come as a suprise.

> I entered a company in the middle of May.  .... I was told to leave last week.

That feels strange. That sounds like you have only been there for two weeks or less.

> My boss told me that he has been closely looking at how much progress I have made

How exactly did he do this? Did you had regular 1:1 check in meetings? Did you had clearly defined tasks/deliverables/stories that he could track? Did he interview other team members? Did he looked at your code check ins or was part of the code review process? How was feedback about your performance provided to you?

> He told me that his company's intention is not to provide training for a new hire

How does he expect the new hire to figure out the code base, dev & deployment processes, tools, Agile/rules etc. ?

> I also accepted what all of them said.

Don't do that until you fully understand how the review process worked and what the accept/fail criteria was. It's possible that your firing has nothing to do with your performance or anything you did.

Comment: The manager was continuously looking at my progress almost very single day. Not the boss himself. I accepted all that was said simply because deep down inside me. I also knew that somehow we were not a good fit.

Comment: @JC6T - When you say boss, whom do you refer to exactly, your supervisor?  Isn’t your manager your supervisor?

Comment: @Donald , One person is the owner or the company. Anther person has the designation of supervisor. My supervisor was the one who looked at my progress almost every day.

Answer (score 1):

As already stated, things are clear. Your boss was not satisfied with your work.

The most likely root cause of this is bad communication - namely, the communication of expectations.

Your boss did not make it clear enough that he **expects** you to use  that certain library. You did not make it very clear that you **expect** to NOT use that library. Hence, the conflict.

Other details might be important also.

---

> I need an opinion on what happened during my exit

The only thing that happened during "exit" was what was expected to happen. The problem was rooted in the (improper) communication during the "entry".

Comment: It's also possible that the boss is lying out of his ears and that the real reason is something entirely different. Any specifics of "not meeting expectations" should have been communicated earlier in the process

Comment: The OP was under probation, there is really no need for the boss to lie.

Comment: There is no need to tell the truth either (say the company is under economic strugle and decided to start laying people off)